# Firing HelpRequested event, when I click message box Help Button

Tags: .net, vb.net

We have recently migrated a VB6 application to VB.NET. In VB6, F1 help has been displayed for each control with the help of .chm file. In VB.Net, the F1 help file is not displayed.

In VB.Net, I added `helprequested` event:

```
Private Sub Form1_HelpRequested(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal hlpevent As 
System.Windows.Forms.HelpEventArgs) Handles MyBase.HelpRequested 
End SubIn Vb.Net
```

and then F1 help is displayed for each control with the help of HelpRequested event.

The problem is that the HelpRequested event is raised when I call `btnHelp_Click button`:

```
Private Sub btnHelp_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _ Handles btnHelp.Click 
Const SET_DEFAULT_HELP As Integer = 88 
MessageBox.Show("MessageBox Help Button", "Raju help", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,MessageBoxIcon.Warning,MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, 0, _ 
My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & BACKSLASH & HELPFILE1_NAME,HelpNavigator.TopicId,SET_DEFAULT_HELP.ToString()) 
End Sub
```

The HelpRequested event is raised when I the call messagebox help button. `(MessageBox.Show ("Displaying Helpfile"))`

I don't want to raise that HelpRequested event; when I click message box Help Button `btnHelp_Click`. How can I restrict this?

Answer (score 0):

There are some files for download at my site (ClickOnce example and project files):
http://www.help-info.de/en/Visual_Basic_2005/vb_2005.htm

First try the ClickOnce example please. Note there are "Coding Examples" on a tab of this example.

Download the code from my site too. This is VB2005 - I think no problem for you to convert. I don't know what version of IDE you are using. Having always internet connection your users may have "up to date" help by remote help topics (special use case; see button text help goes to my web site).

Why not using Help.ShowHelp? This is code from the example project (see above).

```
Private Sub btnShowHelpTopicId_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnShowHelpTopicId.Click  
Dim sPath As String = Replace(Application.StartupPath.ToString, "\bin", "")  
'// --- Show CHM contents tab and a special topic by TopicID -----  
Help.ShowHelp(Me, sPath & "/hlp/CHM-example.chm", HelpNavigator.TopicId, "20010")  
End Sub
```